# Python Try and Except

Tags: python

So recently, I learned something new which is Try and Except, and I still can't really get how it functions. Here is simple code of block. I would like some explanation on how this codes will run. Dish here refers to an item from dictionary. Note : Either ValueError or KeyError can be raised.

```
try:
    return dish["name"].index(cost["$"])
except KeyError:
    return None
```

Comment: This code must be inside a function since it has return statement. Python tries to execute `dish["name"]` then `.index(cost["$"])`. At any stage if a `ValueError` exception occurs, you handle that in your except block and return a `None` from your function. Any other exception will propagate. If there is no handler for that exception in the upstream caller, It terminates the program.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary gives a good explanation but also worth pointing out that this code has the potential for raising KeyError

Comment: The question has been edited to handle KeyError instead of ValueError even though either of those exceptions could arise. *except (KeyError, ValueError):* might be better

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you have two dictionaries:

```
dish = {"name": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]}
cost = {"$": "A"} # It should be any value in A,B,C,D else it will raise Value Error for dish["name"].index(cost["$"])
```

Now if you want to raise ValueError Then you should search the index of value that does not exist in the list in your case

if I try to do this:

```
# return dish["name"].index(cost["$"]) $ This will raise ValueError if
# cost['$']= "E" because "E" does not exist in dish["name"] list so it will raise value error
```

Let me know if it explains your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Quick example but see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for more info.

Your code will "try" and run the line

```py
    return dish["name"].index(cost["$"])
```

and if there is a `ValueError` then it will execute the code

```py
    return None
```

A `ValueError` is a mathematical error such as division by zero. If your code encounters a `ValueError`, it will run `Return None`, which does nothing. Try replacing  `return None` with something like `print("Exception")` and force a value error to see what will happen.

Comment: Division by zero does **not** raise ValueError